# Ajax requests with subdomains Symfony2 (FOSUserBundle example)

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, routes, fosuserbundle

I have a main domain, site.dev and a subdomain, sub.site.dev.

I have a working connection request with FOSUserBundle, from site.dev.
Now, I want to allowed this request from the subdomain sub.site.dev too.

When I try to do that, I have an error in the debug console :
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://site.dev/ajax/check_login_ajax. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://sub.site.dev' is therefore not allowed access.`

Here is the part of my security.yml file :

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            login_path: fos_user_registration_register

            check_path:      check_login_ajax
            success_handler: user.security.authentication_handler
            failure_handler: user.security.authentication_handler
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
        logout:
            path:   fos_user_security_logout
            target: /
        anonymous:    true
```

I already looked the "host" parameter in routing files, but can't find anything working well for both domain. I thought about 2 firewalls, but it doesn't work too.

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT :** Here, I'm talking about FOSUserBundle routing and Ajax, but I want this solution works for all the ajax requests I choose.

**EDIT 2 :** When I execute the AJAX request you can see under, I have the .fail code executed :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myRoute,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            _username: $('#co_username').val(),
            _password: $('#co_password').val(),
            _remember_me: false,
            _csrf_token: $('#co__csrf_token').val()
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log('1');
    }).fail(function (data) {
        console.log('2');
    });
```

**EDIT 3 :** I just figured that an AJAX request is performed but nothing appears in the Symfony2 debug toolbar. So, I executed this code, to try :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Routing.generate('check_login_ajax'),
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#connection-form').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('3');
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log('1');
    }).fail(function (data) {
        console.log('2');
    });
```

'2' is still printed but I'm connected afterwards though.

How should work the `ajaxSubmit` with my code ? Do I have to include an extern library of jQuery ? And what's really the point of it ? Not sure to get everything

**EDIT 4 :** the statusText of my query is "OK" and the status is "200", so, why the .fail code is it executed... ?

**EDIT 5 :** To really understand the situation.
I'm redirected to inscription/ when I try to reach check_login_ajax.
Here is a preview of my debug developer toolbar

[image: debug developer toolbar]

As you can see in my firewall, a login_path is set `login_path: fos_user_registration_register`. fos_user_registration_register being the inscription/ route.

When I execute the AJAX request which is in EDIT 3, I have the results :

```
200
OK
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your .htaccess under web folder:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://sub.site.dev"
</IfModule>
```

don't forget to change "http://sub.site.dev" with your real subdomain.

For EDIT 2

Try to implement AJAX like this :

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "{{path('check_login_ajax')}}",
           data: $("#idForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {

           }
       });
```

Also you can use [AjaxSubmit](https://github.com/malsup/form/)

```
$(this).ajaxSubmit({
      url: "{{path('check_login_ajax')}}",
      type: "POST",
      success: function (result){

      }
)};
```

I hope this help.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean web/.htaccess or really at the root of all the project, as the same level as composer*, .gitignore, etc ?

Comment: I just created .htaccess in my site directory, I added `<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "sub.site.dev"
</IfModule>`but nothing happened. So, I remove this file and tried to add it to web/.htaccess but still nothing is happening...

Comment: Sorry, yes add these lines in .htaccess in your web folder. normally, it is already created the .htaccess just add lines.

Comment: Thank you, I think it's better now. I have no error displayed, but my AJAX request is not performed. I will take a look inside the JS code and I will give you a feedback !

Comment: See my EDIT5 (preceded by EDIT 3 and 4) for more details @Tungenius ! Thank you !

Comment: If you want to use AjaxSubmit. You must import the library. You will find it in github repository.